# How to recover a deleted .sln?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I did a terrible mistake. I copied a backup of my program and forgot to put the .sln file into the backup folder. 
My new revisited version crashed so I wanted to recover my backup and saw that I dont have the .sln file in it.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Whats different about your original version and your revised version?  Can you just copy the revised SLN to the backup location?

Comment: I tried that but it is not working. There are different values in the labels. I changed datatabels and so on.

Comment: What do you mean? "*it is not working*" doesn't tell us anything. And labels are controls, and datalabels are Chart properties, niether should be in your SLN.

Comment: AFAIK, if it's not in your Recycle folder, and you don't have any disk backups and you don't have some kind of source-code control (like VSS), then you either have try to revert your current one through editing, or try to reconstruct it by making a new solution and adding all of your project files back into it.

Comment: looks line the last answer is the case... i thought there is just a way to recover the .sln file out of the working folder... I am already writing everything again...

Comment: you dont nned .sln file only the .vbproj double click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your backup Folder seach `.vbproj` then double click on it

if you had a form named form1 so find form1.vb on your folder (backup) open it with notepad you will find all the code copy/paste it in your new form1